# using fetch in react useEffect hook results in error "Nothing was returned from render. This usually ..."

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

The class component was converted into functional component.. the class component works fine whereas the functional component returns an error. Here are the class and functional components.

```
const LoadFile =(props)=> {
    
    const {file, setFile} = useState(null)

    useEffect(()=>{
        fetch(props.url)
        .then(res => {
            res.text()
        })
        .then(f => setFile(f))
        }
    )
    
    return (
        file && props.children(file)
    );
}

class LoadFile__ extends Component {
    state = {
        file: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(this.props.url)
            .then(res => res.text())
            .then(file => {
                this.setState({ file })
            })
    }

    render() {
        const { file } = this.state;

        return (
            file && this.props.children(file)
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `this.props.children` that is is a function consuming a "file" and not valid JSX? This seems highly irregular. The syntax for your `useState` destructuring is incorrect, `useState` returns an array.

Comment: @DrewReese It's sort of like using a render prop. You could use it as `<LoadFile ...>{(...args) => (<>something</>)}</LoadFile>`

Comment: @Yoshi Ah, I see, basically "override" a prop what most would consider to be, you know, actual children, but you are right, it's just a prop. Thanks.